# How to optimize multiple arrays in R?

Tags: r, optimization, multidimensional-array

I need minimize a funtion based in [Hsieh Model](https://mj-ribeiro.github.io/hsieh.pdf), using R language. The main objective is to minimize a distance function that depends on a set of other functions.

```
obj = function(x1){
  s = sf()
  h_til = h_tilf()
  w_til = w_tilf(x1)
  w_r = w_rf()
  p_ir = p_irf()
  #H_tr = H_trf(x1)
  W = Wf(x1)      
  f1 = matrix(0, i, r)
  f2 = matrix(0, i, r)    

  for (c in 1:i){
    for (j in 1:r){
      f1[c, j] = ( (W[c, j] - W_t[c, j]) / W_t[c, j] ) ** 2
      f2[c, j] = ( (p_ir[c, j] - p_t[c, j])  /  p_t[c, j] ) ** 2
}
}
    d1 = sum(f1)
    d2 = sum(f2)
    D = d1 + d2    
    return(D)  
}
```

Therefore, my algorithm must find three parameters (w, tau_w, tau_h) that minimize this distance function. These three parameters are arrays with i rows and r columns. Given by:

```
w = runif(i*r, 0, 1)
tau_w =  runif(i*r, -1, 1)
tau_h = runif(i*r, -1, 1)

x1 = array( c(tau_w, tau_h, w), dim = c(i, r, 3))
```

I trying solve this using optimx and Rsolnp libraries.

```
res = optim(x1,      #starting values 
            obj)   #function to optimise
```

But i get this error:

```
Error in x1[c, j, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

This minimization is usually done using the Nelder-Mead algorithm.
I'm beginner in optimization and apreciate any help. My complete code is [here](https://github.com/mj-ribeiro/Finances/blob/master/Finance_R/Hsieh%20Model.R).

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of the array `x1` are lost when you do `optim(x1, obj)`. So the error you get is returned by `w_tilf(x1)` because it involves `x1[c,j,1]`.

Reconstruct the array at the beginning of the `obj` function:

```
obj = function(x1){
  x1 = array(x1, dim = c(i, r, 3))
  s = sf()
  ......
}
```

Then `opt <- optim(x1, obj)` should work now. It will return the solution in the `opt$par` field as a vector, you will have to do `array(opt$par, dim = c(i, r, 3))` to get an array.